# Pygame: sound only playing 8 times, then off 4 times, then on, then off, then back on

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I'm having an odd phenomenon where my sound file is playing 8 times, then off, then playing, then off, then playing again.

```
import sys, pygame, os, time

# Force static position of screen
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'

# to get rid of sound lag
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 8, 2048)

# Runs imported module
pygame.init()

# Constants
UP = 'up'
DOWN = 'down'
BOOSTSP = 12
NORMSP = 8

WIN_W = 920
WIN_H = 570
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

PADDLE_HEIGHT = 440
BALL_WIDTH = BALL_HEIGHT = 20

class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

class Paddle(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.speed = 8
        self.pWidth = 20
        self.score = 0
        self.pHeight = PADDLE_HEIGHT
        self.paddle = pygame.Surface((self.pWidth, self.pHeight))
        self.paddle = self.paddle.convert()
        self.lp_moveUP = self.lp_moveDOWN = self.rp_moveUP = self.rp_moveDOWN = False

    def update(self, down, up):
        # Adjust speed
        if up or down or up or down:
            if up:
                self.y -= self.speed
            if down:
                self.y += self.speed

        # paddle movement
        if self.y < 0:
            self.y = 0
        if self.y > WIN_H - self.pHeight:
            self.y = WIN_H - self.pHeight

class Ball(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.speed = [-5, -5]
        self.ball = pygame.Surface((BALL_WIDTH, BALL_HEIGHT))
        self.ball = self.ball.convert()
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(WIN_W/2, WIN_H/2-(BALL_HEIGHT/2), BALL_WIDTH, BALL_HEIGHT)

    def restart(self, lPaddle, rPaddle, screen):
        time.sleep(2)
        self.rect.y = WIN_H/2-(BALL_HEIGHT/2)
        self.rect.x = WIN_W/2
        lPaddle.y = (WIN_H/2) - (PADDLE_HEIGHT/2)
        rPaddle.y = (WIN_H/2) - (PADDLE_HEIGHT/2)

        return True
```

Notice that in the 'update' method, I am playing a sound if the ball hits the paddle. You can see that I print the return value of the 'playSound' function which is the return value of the play() method.

```
    def update(self, lPaddle, rPaddle, sound, playSound):
        # If ball hits the top or bottom
        if self.rect.top < 0 or self.rect.top > WIN_H - BALL_HEIGHT:
            self.speed[1] = -self.speed[1]
            print playSound(sound["bop"], 1)

        # If ball hits paddle
        if(self.speed[0] < 0):
            if (self.rect.left > lPaddle.x + lPaddle.pWidth - 15 and self.rect.left < lPaddle.x + lPaddle.pWidth-10) and (self.rect.top > lPaddle.y and self.rect.top < (lPaddle.y + lPaddle.pHeight)):
                self.speed[0] = -self.speed[0]
                print playSound(sound["beep"], 1)
        else:
            if (self.rect.left > rPaddle.x - 15 and self.rect.left < rPaddle.x - 5) and (self.rect.top > rPaddle.y and self.rect.top < (rPaddle.y + rPaddle.pHeight)):
                self.speed[0] = -self.speed[0]
                print playSound(sound["beep"], 1)

        self.rect = self.rect.move(self.speed)


# Returns True for .5 seconds, then False for .5 seconds.
def checkTime(cur, beg):
    return (cur - beg) % 1000 < 500


# Takes in string, (x, y) and size. Returns text and rect.
def txtRect(sen, xpos, ypos, size):
    phrase = pygame.font.Font(None, size)
    phrase = phrase.render(sen, 1, BLACK)
    phraseRect = phrase.get_rect()
    phraseRect.x = xpos
    phraseRect.y = ypos

    return phrase, phraseRect


# Loads sound files
def playSound(sound, volume):
    sound.set_volume(volume)
    return sound.play()


# Loads sound files
def loadSound():
    sound = {}
    sound["beep"] = pygame.mixer.Sound("sound/beep.ogg")
    sound["boom"] = pygame.mixer.Sound("sound/boom.ogg")
    sound["bop"] = pygame.mixer.Sound("sound/bop.ogg")
    sound["choose"] = pygame.mixer.Sound("sound/choose.ogg")
    sound["count"] = pygame.mixer.Sound("sound/count.ogg")
    sound["end"] = pygame.mixer.Sound("sound/end.ogg")
    sound["music"] = pygame.mixer.Sound("sound/music.ogg")
    sound["select"] = pygame.mixer.Sound("sound/select.ogg")

    return sound


def main():
    size = WIN_W, WIN_H
    fps = 60

    # Used for count down
    countDown = 3
    decrement = True

    pygame.display.set_caption('Pong')
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.SRCALPHA)

    # Create our objects
    ball = Ball((WIN_W/2)-(BALL_WIDTH/2), WIN_H/2-(BALL_HEIGHT/2))
    lPaddle = Paddle(WIN_W/15, (WIN_H/2)-(PADDLE_HEIGHT/2))
    rPaddle = Paddle(WIN_W/1.1, (WIN_H/2)-(PADDLE_HEIGHT/2))

    # Create sound objects
    sound = loadSound()

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    beg_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    intro = count = play = outro = True
    lp_moveUP = lp_moveDOWN = rp_moveDOWN = rp_moveUP = False

    while intro:
        # Print background
        screen.fill(WHITE)

        # Title Text: Pong
        text = txtRect("Pong", 0, 0, 200)
        text = txtRect("Pong", WIN_W/2-(text[1].width/2), WIN_H/4, 200)
        screen.blit(text[0], text[1])

        # Blinking Text: Click here to start
        text = txtRect("- Click here to start -", 0, 0, 50)
        text = txtRect("- Click here to start -", WIN_W/2-(text[1].width/2), WIN_H/1.7, 50)
        if checkTime(beg_time, pygame.time.get_ticks()):
            screen.blit(text[0], text[1])

        # Checks if window exit button pressed
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN or pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_RETURN] != 0:
                screen.blit(text[0], text[1])
                pygame.display.flip()
                playSound(sound["select"], .3)
                pygame.time.wait(1500)
                intro = False

        # Limits frames per iteration of while loop
        clock.tick(fps)
        # Writes to main surface
        pygame.display.flip()

    # Gameplay
    while play:
        # Print background
        screen.fill(WHITE)
        screen.blit(lPaddle.paddle, (lPaddle.x, lPaddle.y))
        screen.blit(rPaddle.paddle, (rPaddle.x, rPaddle.y))
        screen.blit(ball.ball, ball.rect)

        # Print Score
        sen = "Player 1 score: " + str(lPaddle.score)
        text = txtRect(sen, WIN_W/6.5, WIN_H/57, 40)
        screen.blit(text[0], text[1])
        sen = "Player 2 score: " + str(rPaddle.score)
        text = txtRect(sen, WIN_W - WIN_W/6.5 - text[1].width, WIN_H/57, 40)
        screen.blit(text[0], text[1])

        # Countdown
        if count:
            text = txtRect(str(countDown), 0, 0, 75)
            text = txtRect(str(countDown), WIN_W/3.5 - (text[1].width/2), WIN_H/4, 75)
            screen.blit(text[0], text[1])
            text = txtRect(str(countDown), WIN_W/1.4 - (text[1].width/2), WIN_H/4, 75)
            screen.blit(text[0], text[1])

            # Writes to main surface
            pygame.display.flip()

            playSound(sound["count"], 1)
            time.sleep(1)
            countDown -= 1

            # bug fix: prevent display of 0.
            if countDown == 0:
                count = False

        # Gameplay
        else:
            # Checks if window exit button pressed
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

                # Keyboard mechanics
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        rp_moveUP = True
                        rp_moveDOWN = False

                    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        rp_moveUP = False
                        rp_moveDOWN = True
                    if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                        lp_moveUP = True
                        lp_moveDOWN = False

                    elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                        lp_moveUP = False
                        lp_moveDOWN = True

                elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        rp_moveUP = False
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        rp_moveDOWN = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                        lp_moveUP = False
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                        lp_moveDOWN = False

            lPaddle.update(lp_moveDOWN, lp_moveUP)
            rPaddle.update(rp_moveDOWN, rp_moveUP)
            ball.update(lPaddle, rPaddle, sound, playSound)

            # If ball moves off the screen
            if ball.rect.left < 0 - ball.rect.width or ball.rect.left > WIN_W + ball.rect.width:
                if ball.rect.left < 0:
                    rPaddle.score += 1
                elif ball.rect.left > WIN_H + ball.rect.width:
                    lPaddle.score += 1
                playSound(sound["end"], 1)
                count = ball.restart(lPaddle, rPaddle, screen)
                countDown = 3

        # Game ends
        if lPaddle.score == 3 or rPaddle.score == 3:
            playSound(sound["boom"], 1)
            break

        # Limits frames per iteration of while loop
        clock.tick(fps)
        # Writes to main surface
        pygame.display.flip()

    # Gameplay
    while outro:
        # Print background
        screen.fill(WHITE)

        # End Text: Player wins
        if lPaddle.score == 3 or rPaddle.score == 3:
            if lPaddle.score == 3:
                sen = "Player 1 Wins!"
            else:
                sen = "Player 2 Wins!"

            text = txtRect(sen, 0, 0, 40)
            text = txtRect(sen, WIN_W/2-(text[1].width/2)-130, WIN_H/4, 100)

        screen.blit(text[0], text[1])

        text = txtRect("- Click here to continue -", 0, 0, 50)
        text = txtRect("- Click here to continue -", WIN_W/2-(text[1].width/2), WIN_H/1.7, 50)
        # Blinking Text: Click here to start
        if checkTime(beg_time, pygame.time.get_ticks()):
            screen.blit(text[0], text[1])

        # Checks if window exit button pressed
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN or pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_RETURN] != 0:
                screen.blit(text[0], (WIN_W/2-(text[1].width/2), WIN_H/1.7))
                pygame.display.flip()
                loadSound("choose", 1)
                pygame.time.wait(1500)
                outro = False
                main()

        # Limits frames per iteration of while loop
        clock.tick(fps)
        # Writes to main surface
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I play, the intro sounds play and then when the ball bounces off the paddles, the program only plays 8 times with the exact same result every time I play the game. Here is my output. Any help would be much appreciated.

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Users/DanielLee/PycharmProjects/newPong/pong7_sound.py

Channel object at 0x1002c42e8

Channel object at 0x1002c42e8

Channel object at 0x1002c42e8

Channel object at 0x1002c42e8

Channel object at 0x1002c42e8

Channel object at 0x1002c42e8

Channel object at 0x1002c42e8

Channel object at 0x1002c42e8

None

None

None

None

Channel object at 0x1002c42e8

None

Channel object at 0x1002c42e8

Channel object at 0x1002c42e8

Answer (score 0):

The reason I believe the sound was playing then not playing had something to do with the channel being used repeatedly. The solution was to set a 'maxtime' for the sound, turning it off and freeing up the channel for later use.

from documentation: play(loops=0, maxtime=0, fade_ms=0)

As can be seen in the documentation for play(), the second argument is 'maxtime' which can be set to ensure that channels will be available.

I don't have a clear understanding of the mechanics of how this works exactly or even if my understanding of the error is valid, so any clarification would be appreciated.